# forcing a parameter to be integral in nonlinear fitting in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, non-linear-regression, model-fitting

Using the function `lsqcurvefit` in MATLAB, how can one enforce integer type for one of the parameters? The particular parameter in question is an index for a vector so only integer values make sense; however, the fitting routine might try arbitrary real values for the parameter during iteration.

Comment: [Integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) is a major sub-field of numerical optimization—and it is *hard*: see this Matlab article on [mixed integer–linear programs](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/integer-programming.html), but `lsqcurvefit` is more general than linear programs.

Comment: You could try running `lsqcurvefit` and, in your objective function, just `round` the “integer” elements of the vector—the minimization routine will try floats of course but may notice that changes <0.5 don’t make a difference in the objective function, which depending on the problem, might land it in a local minima, or actually find a good solution.

Comment: Unless you’re in a field where integer programming is a common technique, I’d try hard to reformulate the problem to avoid the integer constraint. Perhaps if there aren’t trillions of indexes, you can hold the integer index fixed and run the `lsqcurvefit` on *each* integer (brute-force search over all indexes), and pick the index with the minimum error?

Comment: @AhmedFasih: Thanks, these are all good suggestions. I had also thought about rounding the integer. The vector is not not large (only 300 to 500) but I would be optimizing two parameters, a lower and upper index into the vector, so the total number of iterations in a brute-force approach would be up something like the 300th (or 500th) triangular number.

Comment: Ah, 2D grid search … you may get lucky: if the error function is smoothly-varying over the two indexes, you can skip 5 or 10? I mean, instead of `for i=1:N; for j=i:N; err(j,i) = fminsearch(@(x) objective(x, i, j), init); end; end`, you could do `SKIP = 5; for i=1 : SKIP : N; for j=i : SKIP : N; err(j,i) = fminsearch(@(x) objective(x, i, j), init); end; end` ?

Comment: @AhmedFasih: That's true, and then I could reduce the skip interval once the coarse-grained analysis has completed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

user001,

The lsqcurvefit parameters are ( fun (a function), X0 real vector/array initial point, xdata real vector/array input data, ydata real vector/array Response Data from model, ub real vector/array upper bound on variables, lb real vector/array lower bound on variables)

I didn't see any index values just arrays or vectors and a function

Maybe, your MatLab version is different than mine?
sample below:

```
X0 = [100,-1]; fun = @(x,xdata)x(1)*exp(x(2)*xdata);

lb = [0,-2];  
ub = [3/4,-1];

xdata = ...
    [0.9 1.5 13.8 19.8 24.1 28.2 35.2 60.3 74.6 81.3];
ydata = ...
    [455.2 428.6 124.1 67.3 43.2 28.1 13.1 -0.4 -1.3 -1.5];
```

Comment: We have the same setup. Basically, I want one of my "x" values to be obligatorily integral, the reason being that the objective function contains a discrete convolution over a domain that is represented by a subset of a vector, the bounds of which can shift but only in integer amounts. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that, nonlinear was explicit in your question.  This toolbox may have something http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2016a/pdf_doc/stats/index.html I don't know if you have access to it or not.